Layer creation by running a SQL query in DB manager tool (QGIS)
I just would like to know if there is a way to create a new layer among the virtual layers of a QGIS project, by running a CREATE TABLE statement in the DB manager tool?

Just to clarify you want to create a virtual layer or to create a "real" layer ?

I would like to create a virtual layer; since I can save it if the result of the query is satisfying. To be more specific I would like to know if there is a similar way to create a virtual layer in a qgis project, using the DB manager tool, with a query like "CREATE TABLE *** AS SELECT (rest of the query here)".

Why using the DB manager rather than the Add virtual layer ? the query will be the same (you just omit the "CREATE TABLE *** AS" part)
